# How to customize com.liferay.portlet.wiki.action.GetPageAttachmentAction using Ext Plugin

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am using Liferay 6.2 and I want to modify `GetPageAttachmentAction`.

I want to add the following code in `strutsExecute` to include the title in the file name:

```java
public ActionForward strutsExecute(
        ActionMapping actionMapping, ActionForm actionForm,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws Exception {
    long nodeId = ParamUtil.getLong(request, "nodeId");
    String title = ParamUtil.getString(request, "title");
    String fileName = ParamUtil.getString(request, "fileName");
    // Here my change:
    int pos = fileName.indexOf(CharPool.SLASH); 
    if (pos >= 0) { 
        title = fileName.substring(0, pos); 
        fileName = fileName.substring(pos + 1);
    }
    ...
```

If I create a hook plugin for this change by extending BaseStrutsPortletAction with a custom class then it does not provide strutsExecute() to override.

Should I go with an Ext plugin instead? If yes, then suggest me the configuration of the Ext plugin to modify GetPageAttachmentAction.

Comment: Can you show what you wanted to change in the `strutsExecute`?

Comment: I want to add code in getFile() method called by strutExecute() method to seperate file wiki title and file name. So I want to add following code                                                                                                     int pos = fileName.indexOf(CharPool.SLASH);

  if (pos != -1) {
   title = fileName.substring(0, pos);
   fileName = fileName.substring(pos + 1);
  }

Comment: I integrated that information into your question

Answer (score 0):

You can do either: Hook plugin or Ext plugin.

But a hook seems to make more sense here:

```java
public class MyGetPageAttachmentAction extends BaseStrutsPortletAction {

  public void processAction(
      StrutsPortletAction originalStrutsPortletAction,
      PortletConfig portletConfig, ActionRequest actionRequest,
      ActionResponse actionResponse)
      throws Exception {

    String title = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "title");
    String fileName = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "fileName");

    // Your code:
    int pos = fileName.indexOf(CharPool.SLASH); 
    if (pos >= 0) { 
      title = fileName.substring(0, pos); 
      fileName = fileName.substring(pos + 1);
    }

    // Wrap request to add your new parameters (the original request parameters are immutable)
    DynamicActionRequest dynamicActionRequest = new DynamicActionRequest(actionRequest, true);
    dynamicActionRequest.setParameter("fileName", fileName);
    dynamicActionRequest.setParameter("title", title);

    // And delegate to original action
    originalStrutsPortletAction.processAction(portletConfig, dynamicActionRequest, actionResponse);
  }
}
```

(From your question I guess that you already have the correct settings in liferay-hook.xml)